# Customizing CKEditor's toolbar during runtime

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a website using CKEditor. Now I  want to customize the toolbar "live" during runtime, without having to create a new instance of the editor.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Related discussion in the CKEditor forums: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Change-Toolbar-Runtime

Comment: i have got solution.I am using ckeditor.replace and it works now.Thank you all.

Comment: But that will create a new instance of the editor? Anyway, if it works for you, all is well.

Comment: You are rite It will create a new instance. But i destroy the old one and then use replace.

Comment: Close the question or add answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution.I am using ckeditor.replace and it works now.
I am destroy the existing instance and then try to use replace.Actually replace will create a new instance.